# Gnucash: Is there a way to flag a transaction?

Tags: gnucash

When I'm reconciling my accounts it would be very useful if I could flag/mark a transaction.  I'm not talking about using the R field.  Perhaps another column that would let me mark the transaction as okay or for later processing.  I haven't been able to find that feature in Gnucash -- does it exist?

Answer (score 4):

I put “***” in the description of transactions that need to be reviewed as a way to mark them. They are easy to spot later, or search for to find.

Comment: That could be helpful.  I'll start using that.  Thanks, @chrisg.  :>)